# Import Active Directory all data into Openldap

Tags: linux, active-directory, openldap

I am trying to replicate Active Directory structure into in an Openldap on Centos 7.

I have configured Openldap as per instructions given in below link 
http://www.learnitguide.net/2016/01/configure-openldap-server-on-rhel7.html

I have .ldif file exported from Active Directory (I am not sure how it is exported).

Now when I trying to import .ldif into an opendap using below command

```
    ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=xxx,dc=org" -f /root/abc.ldif
```

getting error

```
[root@ldapmach cn=config]# ldapadd -x -W -D  "cn=Manager,dc=xxx,dc=org" -f /root/abc.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
adding new entry "CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=xxx,DC=org"
ldap_add: Undefined attribute type (17)
additional info: instanceType: attribute type undefined
```

There are many such attributes present into AD Ldif file which are not recognized by Openldap.

Can anyone help to import these AD data into openldap.

Please let me know in case of more information required.

Comment: You have to [export the schema](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.04.schema.aspx?pr=blog) from the source AD first and import that to your openldap. Or there might be an switch for ldapadd to ignore that kind of errors.

Comment: @OcasoProtal , Thanks . So If I get the schema exported from the source AD , how do I import it in Openldap?

Comment: Just like any other ldif file, but you have to take care of the correct path. See e.g. http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1442.html or do a search on http://serverfault.com/ or see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961744.aspx for explanation of the schema container

Answer (score 0):

The standard LDAP schema supplied with OpenLDAP do not include all the attributes required to import LDIF files from Active Directory.
For this reason, some of the schemas must be edited to include the following attributes:

See at

https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1461.html